# How To Get "random.randint(a,b)" To Give Me Different Values Over A Range?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

Fairly new to working with the "Pseudo Random Generators". From my understanding I should either "seed" the generator or let it run on "current system time." The "randint()" function already has a system to where it can pick different values. My problem is trying to get the different values printed in a range. Example:

```
import random                         
#imports random function
get_int_ = random.randint(1,10)       
#gets values from 1,10 
for _ in xrange(15):                  
#gets values in range of 15
    print get_int_
```

What I am trying to do is get the "randint(1,10)" value to pick values from 1-10 (Any of which can be repeated more than once) on to a range of 15 (Meaning I want these values to be printed 15 times) 
Thank you all input and corrections on code are highly appreciated!

Comment: Call randint 15 times?

Comment: I do not understand? @user2864740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `randint` repeatedly to get it to give you different random numbers.

```
import random                         

for _ in xrange(15):
    print random.randint(1,10)
```

`randint` just returns an `int` when you call it, not a generator or iterator. Accessing that `int` repeatedly will not change its value. Instead, just call the `randint` function itself repeatedly, so that it generates a new number each time.

Comment: What about getting different results every time?